# How can I float an unordered list (ul) to the right of an image without specifying fixed widths

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I am trying to float an unordered list to the right of an image. My html looks like this:

```
<img src="..." class="left" alt="" />
<h3>Internet Explorer Shortcut keys</h3>
<ul>
<li>Go to the web page that you want to view</li>
<li><strong>Explorer Shortcut keys</strong>: Press <strong>Shift+F12</strong> and the code should appear in a separate window</li>
<li>If this does not work, hold the mouse pointer over a blank part of the web page, right click and choose "<em>HTML</em>".</li>
<li>Alternatively from the menu bar select <em>View</em> and choose "<em>HTML</em>" or "<em>Source</em>" depending on the version you are using.</li>
</ul>
```

The css is fairly complicated but looks somehting like this:

```
.itemFullText ul {margin:20px 0 30px 10px;padding-left:0px;list-style:none;float:left;}
.itemFullText ul li {margin:0 0 6px;padding:0 0 0 30px;float:none;background:url(http://www.jeyjoo.com/img/s.png) -381px 0px no-repeat;line-height:22px;font_weight:bolder;display:block;}
.itemFullText ul li {
    background: url("http://www.jeyjoo.com/img/s.png") no-repeat scroll -381px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    float: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

The actual page is [here](http://jeyjoo.com/blog/how-to-view-the-code-behind-a-website).
Thanks

Comment: If those interested, I actually found a great fix to this: remove the float:left form ul and add an overflow hidden: ul {overflow:hidden;} . This stops the bullet points hiding behind a left floated image.

Comment: I wish I could upvote that comment more! `Overflow:hidden` works for a right-floated image too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to use [CSS3 flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Wrap the `ul`/`img` elements and then set the `display` of the wrapper element to `flex`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam interdum facilisis posuere.</li>
    <li>Mauris pellentesque, sem a cursus dignissim, turpis sem mollis nisl, id dignissim sem quam at leo. Etiam rutrum sit amet metus eget feugiat. Sed egestas accumsan augue at efficitur.</li>
    <li> Quisque erat arcu, eleifend consectetur semper vel, semper non metus. Cras sed magna metus. Maecenas auctor lacus nec ligula fermentum congue. Aenean a hendrerit ex. Curabitur eu nisi velit. Duis a dignissim tortor.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could also use CSS tables and set the `display` of the wrapper element to `table` and then set the `display` of the children `ul`/`img` elements to `table-cell`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.wrapper ul,
.wrapper img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam interdum facilisis posuere.</li>
    <li>Mauris pellentesque, sem a cursus dignissim, turpis sem mollis nisl, id dignissim sem quam at leo. Etiam rutrum sit amet metus eget feugiat. Sed egestas accumsan augue at efficitur.</li>
    <li> Quisque erat arcu, eleifend consectetur semper vel, semper non metus. Cras sed magna metus. Maecenas auctor lacus nec ligula fermentum congue. Aenean a hendrerit ex. Curabitur eu nisi velit. Duis a dignissim tortor.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I used a solution based on this (I already have a responsive grid system in place, so used that. This seems to be the only way - a shame that unordered lists do not wrap like a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If the image width is always the same, which is looks like it is (200px), you could remove the float from the `<ul>` and change `padding-left: 0` to `padding-left: 210px`.

I say 210px because that's the width of the image plus an extra 10 to line it up with the heading above it.

Answer (score -1):

Like the OP discovered, setting `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` (oddly) works like a charm!

Comment: I don't know why you got down-voted. It does work. It's got a weird side-effect when in contenteditable on IE, though. It puts resize handles on the OL/UL when you try to select it.